# For long term survival of a species in a harsh environment which is more important-mutation or evolution?

Tags: genetics, evolution, mutations

The environment is the ultimate cause of population stabilization. Considering the environment to turn harsh for the survival of a species.How to adapt better to this change-by evolution or by mutation?

Comment: Considering mutation is part of evolution this question does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: maybe because i am not related to this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the central requirements of evolution is that individuals of a species vary. Natural selection acts on variants. Mutation is the source of variation upon which evolutions works. Variation is then increased through sexual reproduction and recombination. Variation in the environment is the reason that variation among individuals is so important for the long-term survival of a species. Otherwise, it would be best to fix on a single optimal genotype. But with variation in the environment, the optimal is a moving target. So your question is complex. Variation in the environment requires a mechanism for species to adapt to change. That mechanism is mutation, amplified by sexual reproduction and recombination.

Answer (score 1):

To operate for many generations evolution needs a process that adds variation (mutation) and a process that removes it (natural selection). Evolution can operate without mutation but not for very long the process will exhaust the available variation rather quickly.